# HAXM Install Will Not Detect Enabled VT-x

Tags: android, android-studio, virtualization, android-virtual-device, haxm

I've been struggling with this for the past while and can't find any solutions. HAXM seems to be unable to detect that I have Intel Virtualization Technology enabled in my BIOS.

This issue only arose today after updating android studio and was working perfectly before. I've looked over the Intel and stack overflow forums but it has made no difference, Hyper-V is disabled on my PC and my antivirus is the free avg so I am unsure as to what may be causing it.

I've tried installing it through both the SDK manager in Android Studio and manually but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Which version of HAXM you are using?

Comment: 7.2.0 - the most recent one. I found the solution though i think, thanks :)

Comment: I was having a similar issue and downgrading 7.2.0 to 7.1.0 solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!
All you need to do is uninstall it via the control panel, delete any files that may be there from Android Studio and then install it from Intel's [android resources](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-intel-haxm)